Set notation meaning of $U_{1/n} (\xi)$
I am studying real analysis and do not understand the notation:
The set $U_{1/n}(\xi).$ Is this the same as $(\xi-1/n; \xi+1/n)$? Thank you for your help.
I will attach the textbook passage for more context (Harro Heuser, Lehrbuch der Analysis Teil 1. In: Mathematische Leitfäden (2003), page 214) - although it is in German sorry.
Heuser 2003, continuity delta neighbourhood proof, page 214.

See if there is a list of notations either at the beginning or the end of the book.

The notation means whatever the person introducing it says it means. Surely Heuser defines it somehwrer.

He defines it (exemplary on page 84) as the open intervall around Zeta with radius 1/n. Thanks for your help, my midnight brain appreciates it a lot.
